# Enabling Debugging Logs while loading JavaFX Applet

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, javafx-1

My JavaFX app is working when executed via the JavaFX Eclipse plugin.

But when I try to embed it into my web project, it is not being rendered properly and after a while a black rectangle is loaded in it's place.

Here is the code for loading my JavaFX Application:

```
    <script src="http://dl.javafx.com/1.2/dtfx.js"></script>
    <script>
        javafx({
            codebase: "/applets/",
            archive: "HelloApplet.jar",
            draggable: false,
            width: 250,
            height: 80,
            code: "hello.HelloApplet",
            name: "HelloApplet"
       });
    </script>
```

And here is the code for my JavaFX App:

```
    package hello;
    // some imports here
    // ...
    Stage {
      title: "My Applet"
      width: 250
      height: 80
      scene: Scene {
        content: Text {
            x: 10  y: 30
            font: Font { size: 24 }
            fill: Color.BLUE
            effect: DropShadow{ offsetX: 3 offsetY: 3}
            content: "Hello World!"
          } // Text
       } // Scene
    } // Stage
```

In my web project i have placed the generated HelloApplet.jar into:

```
    src/main/webapp/applets/HelloApplet.jar
```

but to no avail it is still not loading what am i doing wrong here? am i missing something?

Is it possible to enable any logging while loading the applet?

Comment: The code is taken from http://jfx.wikia.com/wiki/Applet_Example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, I'm not familiar enough with JavaFX to help you with that, but you can view the console so you can see the stack traces and everything by enabling it in the Control Panel (if you're using Windows):

[image]

Comment: There is this tool called JaNeLA. It really gives details on what is really happening at the back and gives suggestions. you can visit them @ http://pscode.org/janela/

Answer (score 1):

JavaFX applet uses the new Java-Plugin architecture which uses JNLP.  To deploy JavaFX applets you must use both the javascript in html file and the jnlp file. When IDE's generate the jnlp and the html file, they embed default values in those files that you must ensure are correct.  Make sure of the following when you load your files on the web server:

- Your javascript `archive:` key matches the name of the jar file.
- Your javascript `code:` key points to the main class of the applet
- Your javascript `jnlp_href:` key points to the proper location of the jnlp file
- Your jnlp file needs to the codebase referring to the location where the code resides.

Below is a sample:

javascript:

```
<script>
    javafx(
        {
              archive: "applet-demo.jar",
              width: 640,
              height: 75,
              code: "applet.demo.Main",
              name: "applet-demo",
              jnlp_href: "myapplet.jnlp"
        }
    );
</script>
```

myapplet.jnlp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://javafxcookbook.s3.amazonaws.com/ch007/applet-demo" href="myapplet.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>applet-demo</title>
        <vendor>Vladimir Vivien</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://javafxcookbook.s3.amazonaws.com/ch007/applet-demo"/>
        <description>applet-demo</description>
        <offline-allowed/>
        <shortcut>
            <desktop/>
        </shortcut>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.5+"/>
        <extension name="JavaFX Runtime" href="http://dl.javafx.com/1.2/javafx-rt.jnlp"/>
        <jar href="applet-demo.jar" main="true"/>
    </resources>
    <applet-desc name="applet-demo" main-class="com.sun.javafx.runtime.adapter.Applet" width="640" height="75">
        <param name="MainJavaFXScript" value="applet.demo.Main">
    </applet-desc>
    <update check="background">
</jnlp>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the direction of `codebase` in file `JNLP`, which should contain the correct path of your `.jar`.

For example, if I have my `.jar` at `C:\Users\rodrigo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFXJavaScript\dist`, then my JNLP should be `http://localhost:8082/servlet/org.netbeans.modules.javafx.project.JnlpDownloadServlet/C%3A/Users/rodrigo/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXJavaScript/dist/`